# LINQ statement equivalent to sum query in SQL

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have SQL table with data::

```
UserId   POINTS
121        5
122        6
121        4
122        3
121        1
```

To calculate the sum of the points for respective userid

```
SELECT SUM(POINTS) FROM TBL_SCORED_POINTS WHERE UserId = 121;
```

How can I convert this to `LINQ` Query?

```
public class ScoredPointModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }        
        public int ScoredPoints { get; set; }                     
    }
```

In `LINQ` query, I have to make where clause dynamic, I mean the where clause value will come from the user? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for:

```
var total = ScoredPointModels.Where(spm => spm.UserId == userId).Sum(spm => spm.ScoredPoints);
```

Comment: I already mentioned that `UserId` would be dynamic. So why are you using `spm => spm.UserId == 121`.

Comment: Just replace the 121 with a variable set by your user, edited my original asnwer with a variable as example